# Who can change usernames and when would they do it if there's no flag or impersonation of someone else?

Tags: support, display-names

For a short while, [my username on MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/5/nike-dattani?tab=profile) was changed (not by me) to this:

[image]

It's now back to what I originally chose:

[image]

My prior research before asking this question was to check things like "[why did my name change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=why+did+my+name+change%3F)" here on MSE, which lead me to discover that:

- [Shog9 has indeed manually changed a username before, but it was only because they were trying to impersonate someone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174589/391772).
- In one case [a username was accidentally changed from a custom choice to a "userXXXX"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321621/391772) but in my case an actual letter changed which corrupted the integrity of my actual name (my name is not "Nick" which is usually short for "[Nicholas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas)" which is *not my name*).
- Finally, [someone's username was changed from "idiotretard" to something else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156926/391772), because it was flagged for being offensive, but I'm certain that's not what happened to me.

**Which people can change usernames, and when would they do it if there's no flags and there's no impersonating of someone?**

Comment: There's no record of your display name having been changed at all, by anyone, including you.

Comment: @animuson I was worried that records wouldn't be kept, but I took a screenshot of it saying "Nick Dattani". I didn't modify any images. Can you answer "Which people can change usernames, and when would they do it if there's no flags and there's no impersonating of someone?". Someone or some bug in the code changed it (this type of thing doesn't happen due to a random bit-flip in hardware, for example).

Comment: It's more plausible that something on _your system_ changed the page. Maybe even some really weird translation bug. It's simply not possible that there would be zero record of a display name change in our system. No one changed your name. But if you want a direct answer: any diamond moderator can edit a display name. But I would like to emphasize: **no one did that here**.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For what it's worth, if I visit that page with your name in Chrome, right-click, and "Translate to English", I see your name becomes Nick Dattani.

If I visit again, the page is not translated and it's back to Nike. Seems the simplest explanation is that you inadvertently triggered this translation locally, in particular from the information [@animuson shared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366736/who-can-change-usernames-and-when-would-they-do-it-if-theres-no-flag-or-imperso#comment1222104_366736):

> There's no record of your display name having been changed at all, by anyone, including you

Bit of a boring answer, really, but I've accidentally done similar things enough times to sympathize with your startling reaction. Fortunately, this isn't one that leads to any long-lasting consequences.